# I get dashes instead of bullets in \itemize

Tags: formatting, itemize

When I use `\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}`, the items are displayed as dashes.
But I want them to be displayed by bullets.
Those are my headers:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{llncs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage{amsmath}                                
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[algosection, boxruled, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{bl}{rgb}{0.0,0.2,0.6} 
\definecolor{dark-red}{rgb}{0.4,0.15,0.15}
\definecolor{dark-blue}{rgb}{0.15,0.15,0.4}
\definecolor{medium-blue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks, linkcolor={dark-red},
    citecolor={dark-blue}, urlcolor={medium-blue}
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\newtheorem{observation}{\textsc{Observation}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

As far as I've read, the `french` options makes this. But I have `french` nowhere. What could cause this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Your code does only (parts of) a preamble, but no `\begin{document}...\end{document}` section

Comment: The culprit is `llncsdoc`, which has `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{--}`. Do you think you really need it? I don't think so, it's just for typesetting the class manual.

Comment: @egreg I have removed it but nothing changed.

Comment: I had the same issue, but I had a silly mistake. \end{itemize} was missing on one of the earlier pages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of [`llncs.cls`](ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip) as it sets

```
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\normalfont\bfseries --}
\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\m@th\bullet$}
```

meaning first-level `itemize` items will be set with dashes, while second-level items will be set with bullets. You can adjust this by adding to your preamble

```
\let\labelitemi\labelitemii
```

However, consider that for journal submissions, these things should not be altered.

As a showcase of this behaviour, here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}% ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Like this,
  \item and like this.
\end{itemize}

\let\labelitemi\labelitemii

\begin{itemize}
  \item Like this,
  \item and like this.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course the `\let` would make second level itemized list to have the same label as first level lists. I'm not sure this is recommendable.

Comment: The conference requires articles *preferably formatted in the LNCS style*. Does it mean, including the bullets?

Comment: @cagirici: I would think so, since this forms part of their *style*.

Comment: That said, a bullet list is a graphical element. One should be free to choose the graphical elements they wish for their own manuscripts. For example, a figure can have any shape that serves it's purpose best. That LNCS (arbitrarily) chose to put dashes outmost and bullets innermost seems to have little justification (why not in the opposite order?). After all, one could be using their own little package for bullets all along, never noticing that Springer has altered the default `itemize` environment.